# Make a column take the space of missing columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to make a CSS grid with an optional left and right sidebar. HTML looks like this:

```css
.content-inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px auto 300px;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}

.main {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-inner">
  <aside class="left">Left</aside>
  <main class="main">Main</main>
  <aside class="right">Right</aside>
</div>
```

I am not sure if its possible, but I would like for my main content to span the remaining row width if one or both of the sidebars are missing. I am looking for a pure css solution. I know I can swap the class with JS.

Comment: flexbox will do a better job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the aside dimension to 300px, and set the first and last template columns  to auto

```css
.content-inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  margin: 5px;
  
}

.main {
  grid-column: 2;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

aside {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-inner">
  <aside class="left">Left</aside>
  <main class="main">Main</main>
  <aside class="right">Right</aside>
</div>

<div class="content-inner">
  <main class="main">Main</main>
  <aside class="right">Right</aside>
</div>

<div class="content-inner">
  <aside class="left">Left</aside>
  <main class="main">Main</main>
</div>

<div class="content-inner">
  <main class="main">Main</main>
</div>
```

Comment: ohhh I was so close! Thank you for this. Wouldn't I also need to set max-width to 300px now that the column is auto though?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment !   You don't need to set max-width, the second column is 1fr, so it will take the remaining space whatever it is

Comment: Right, but if I have 600px content in the aside I have nothing to keep it constrained to 300 without the max-width correct?

Comment: Well, in this case set the max-width . I thought that the aside didn't have a dimension in their own

Answer (score 0):

Consider leaving all columns in place, and shrinking them to zero when unoccupied. (You would have to add a class to those that would shrink.)

```css
.content-inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
}

.left, .right {
  width: 300px;
}

.absent {
  width: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

/* for demo purposes only */
.content-inner     { margin-bottom: 15px; }
.content-inner > * { border: 1px dashed black; }
```

```html
<div class="content-inner">
  <aside class="left">ASIDE - LEFT</aside>
  <main class="main">MAIN</main>
  <aside class="right">ASIDE - RIGHT</aside>
</div>

<div class="content-inner">
  <aside class="left absent">ASIDE - LEFT</aside>
  <main class="main">MAIN</main>
  <aside class="right">ASIDE - RIGHT</aside>
</div>

<div class="content-inner">
  <aside class="left">ASIDE - LEFT</aside>
  <main class="main">MAIN</main>
  <aside class="right absent">ASIDE - RIGHT</aside>
</div>

<div class="content-inner">
  <aside class="left absent">ASIDE - LEFT</aside>
  <main class="main">MAIN</main>
  <aside class="right absent">ASIDE - RIGHT</aside>
</div>
```